# get nlargest distinct values in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to get top 3 distinct values from a df, nlargest wont work in this case in pandas
Below is my sample df

[image]

Expected O/p:
[image]

Any help wil be much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('Col1').nlargest(1).head(3)`

Answer (score 4):

`sort_values` then `drop_duplicates` and we get the tail 3 rows.

```
df.sort_values('col2').drop_duplicates('col1',keep='last').tail(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`nlargest` will work:

```
df[['col1','col2' ]].drop_duplicates(keep='last').nlargest(10, 'col2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
df.sort_values('val', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('col').head(3).sort_values('col')
```

Output:

```
   col  val
0   A   50
2   B   32
3   C   41
```